# Integration by parts problem?

Tags: integration

$$\int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_{k+1}}(t_{n}-s)^{\alpha-1}f(s)ds$$

where $\int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_{k+1}}f(s)ds=h$ and $t_{k}=t_{0}+kh$ .

The integration by parts formula states:

$$\int_{a}^{b}u(x)v(x)\,dx=u(x)\int_{a}^{b}v(x)dx-\int_{a}^{b}u'(x)\left(\int_{a}^{b}v(x)dx\right)\,dx.$$

by integration by parts $u(s)=(t_{n}-s)^{\alpha-1},v(s)=f(s)$ , thus

$$\int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_{k+1}}(t_{n}-s)^{\alpha-1}f(s)ds=$$

$$ \Big[h(t_{n}-s)^{\alpha-1}\Big]{}_{t_{k-1}}^{t_{k+1}}-(-)h(\alpha-1)\int_{t_{k-1}}^{t_{k+1}}(t_{n}-s)^{\alpha-2}ds= $$

$$\Big[h(t_{n}-s)^{\alpha-1}\Big]{}_{t_{k-1}}^{t_{k+1}}+h(\alpha-1)\Big[-\frac{(t_{n}-s)^{\alpha-1}}{\alpha-1}\Big]{}_{t_{k-1}}^{t_{k+1}}=$$

$$\Big[h(t_{n}-s)^{\alpha-1}\Big]{}_{t_{k-1}}^{t_{k+1}}-\Big[h(t_{n}-s)^{\alpha-1}\Big]{}_{t_{k-1}}^{t_{k+1}}=0$$

This is not right!. where mistake in pervious solutions.

Comment: That is *not* what the integration by parts formula says

Comment: Your integration by parts is awkward, which should be $$\int_{a}^{b}u(x)v(x)\,dx=\left[u(x)\left(\int v(x)\,dx\right)\right]_{x=a}^{b} - \left[\int\left(\int v(x)\,dx\right)\,du(x)\right]_{x=a}^{b}$$ where note $\int v(x)\,dx$ actually means a function of $x$, you can denote as $\mathcal{V}(x)=\int v(x)\,dx$, and should be a part of the integrand in second integral, if that is not obvious to you.

Comment: @Nanayajitzuki thank you

Comment: @Lorago thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integration by parts formula is problematic, because the LHS $$\int_a^b u(x) v(x) \, dx$$ is a function of $a$ and $b$ but not $x$; whereas the RHS $$u(x) \int_a^b v(x) \, dx - \int_a^b u'(x) \left(\int_a^b v(x) \, dx\right) \, dx$$ is a function of $x$ as evidenced by the presence of an unintegrated factor of $u(x)$ in the first term.  As such, it cannot be valid.

Usually we write the IBP relationship as

$$\int u \, dv = uv - \int v \, du,$$
or explicitly writing the variable of integration,
$$\int u(x) v'(x) \, dx = u(x) v(x) - \int v(x) u'(x) \, dx,$$
and for a definite integral, this is
$$\int_a^b u(x) v'(x) \, dx = \Bigl[u(x) v(x) \Bigr]_{x=a}^b - \int_a^b v(x) u'(x) \, dx. \tag{1}$$  Note that I have defined the function $v$ differently than your formula.

With the above in mind, and with the choice

$$u(s) = (t_n - s)^{\alpha - 1}, \quad u'(s) = -(\alpha - 1)(t_n - s)^{\alpha - 2}, \tag{2}$$

$$v'(s) = f(s), \quad v(s) = \int f(s) \, ds, \tag{3}$$

we obtain the indefinite integral
$$\int (t_n - s)^{\alpha - 1} f(s) \, ds
= (t_n - s)^{\alpha - 1} \int f(s) \, ds + (\alpha - 1) \int (t_n - s)^{\alpha - 2} \left( \int f(s) \, ds \right) \, ds \tag{3}$$
Then the corresponding definite integral is
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{t_k}^{t_{k+1}} \!\!\!\! (t_n - s)^{\alpha - 1} f(s) \, ds
&= \left[(t_n - s)^{\alpha - 1} \!\!\! \int \!\!f(s) \, ds \right]_{s=t_k}^{t_{k+1}} \!\!+ (\alpha - 1) \int_{s=t_k}^{t_{k+1}} \!\!\! (t_n - s)^{\alpha - 2} \!\left( \!\int \!\! f(s) \, ds \!\right) ds \\
&= (t_n - s)^{\alpha-1} h + (\alpha - 1) \int_{s=t_k}^{t_{k+1}} \! (t_n - s)^{\alpha - 2} \left( \int f(s) \, ds\right) \, ds. \tag{4}
\end{align}$$

But notice that we cannot "distribute" the limits of integration of the definite integral in the second term of $(4)$ into the antiderivative $\int f(s) \, ds$.  Such an operation is not permitted; e.g.,

$$\int_{x=1}^2 \frac{1}{x} \left( \int x \, dx \right) \, dx = \int_{x=1}^2 \frac{x}{2} \, dx = \left[\frac{x^2}{4}\right]_{x=1}^2 = \frac{3}{4},$$

but
$$\int_{x=1}^2 \frac{1}{x} \left( \int_{x=1}^2 x \, dx \right) \, dx = \int_{x=1}^2 \frac{3}{2x} \, dx = \left[\frac{3}{2} \log x \right]_{x=1}^2 = \frac{3 \log 2}{2} \ne 1.$$

Consequently, without an explicit antiderivative for $f$, it is not possible to simplify the expression $(4)$ any further.

Comment: heropup,  thank you. do you have any another method to solve it?